# Elasticsearch 5.2.0 - Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Tags: elasticsearch

On my Windows 10 machine I'm trying to start Elasticsearch 5.2.0 which fails with a following error:

```
D:\Tools\elasticsearch-5.2.0\bin>elasticsearch.bat
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Right now I have 20GB free RAM.

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the JVM options of Elasticsearch before launch it.

Basically go to your config/jvm.options and change the values of

```
-Xms2g ---> to some megabytes (200 MB)
-Xmx2g ---> to some megabytes (500 MB) 

here 2g refers to 2GB so change to 200MB it should 200m
For example change it to below value
-Xms200m
-Xmx500m
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to the last JDK version 1.8.0_121 64-Bit(I had 1.8.0_90) and the issue is gone